Laravel backpack 404 on "Show" button for the soft-deleted items
When I try to "show" an entry using Backpack ShowOperation, and that entry has been soft-deleted, the application throws a 404 not found.
Is it possible to display the soft-deleted entries in the show operation ?

There is a configuration for that in config/backpack/operations/show.php.
You can use it to achieve the desired behavior.
https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/blob/9181d89a96c4f2c356e65547d404741400883111/src/config/backpack/operations/show.php#L20
Cheers

By default 'softDeletes' set as false, after I update value getting a blank page!
I am using backpack:5.x

You have not preview view for deleted items, in Backpack docs you can find information about Trash operation, this have a special view to restore or permanent delete the item. If you handle your CRUD in a special way need to know by default deleted items are hide.
Make sure to read docs about Trash Operation to implemented correctly.

I am using Backpack:5.x setAccessCondition is not available
